# Prove that $\mathbb{Z}^r$/$\mathbb{DZ}^r$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$/d1 x $\mathbb{Z}$/d2 $\times$.....x$\mathbb{Z}$/dr.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Here $\mathbb{D}$ is an $r\times r$ diagonal matrix with diagonal entries d1, d2,..., dr where d1|d2|...|dr. This is the last step of the proof of fundamental theorem of finitely generated Abelian groups by my instructor, which I am unable to understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a map:

\begin{align*}
f\colon \mathbb{Z}^r/ \mathbb{D}\mathbb{Z}^r &\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}/d_1\mathbb{Z}
\times\dots\times \mathbb{Z}/d_r \mathbb{Z}\\
(x_1,\dots,x_r) + \mathbb{D}\mathbb{Z}^r &\longmapsto (x_1 + d_1\mathbb{Z},\dots, x_r + d_r \mathbb{Z})
\end{align*}

Excercise: show that $f$ is a homomorphism. Now to see that $f$ is injective consider the image $\overline{(x_1,\dots,x_r)}$ of a sequence $(x_1,\dots,x_r)\in\mathbb{Z}^r$ in $\mathbb{Z}^r/\mathbb{D}\mathbb{Z}^r$ satisfying $f\overline{(x_1,\dots,x_r)} = 0$. We have
\begin{align*}
x_1 &\equiv 0 \mod{d_1}\\
&\vdots\\
x_r &\equiv 0 \mod{d_r}
\end{align*}
and hence there exist integers $m_1,\dots, m_r$ such that $x_i = m_i d_i$ for $i=1,\dots,r$. Thus:
\begin{align*}
\overline{(x_1,\dots,x_r)} &= (m_1 d_1,\dots, m_r d_r)\\
&\equiv (0,\dots,0) \mod \{(q_1 d_1,\dots, q_r d_r)\mid q_i\in\mathbb{Z}\}.
\end{align*} Hence $f$ is injective. It is also easy to see that $f$ is surjective, hence it is a bijection.

Comment: Is $\mathbb{Z}$/d1 same as $\mathbb{Z}$/d1$\mathbb{Z}$? @user259242

Comment: @AnjaniGupta Yes that's right.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\pi: \def\Z{\mathbf Z}\Z^r \to \prod \Z/(d_i)$ denote the product of the natural projections, that is the map 
$$ \pi(z) = (z_1 + d_1\Z, \ldots, z_r + d_r\Z) $$
Then $\pi$ is a group homomorphism. To show that $\pi$ is onto, note that the natural maps $\Z \to \Z/(d_i)$ is onto, hence their product is also (given $k_i+d_i\Z\in \Z/(d_i)$, $k:=(k_1, \ldots, k_r)$ is mapped to $(k_i + d_i\Z)_i$ by $\pi$).

Now compute $\pi$'s kernel, we have 
\begin{align*}
  z \in \ker \pi &\iff \pi(z)= 0\\
                 &\iff \forall i: z_i \in d_i\Z\\
                 &\iff z \in D\Z^r
\end{align*}
As $Dz = (d_1z_1, \ldots, d_rz_r)$ for $z \in \Z^r$. Therefore
$$ \Z^r/\ker \pi = \Z^r /D \Z^r \cong \prod_i \Z/(d_i) $$